# How do I dig deeper in the Performance panel for a function call that consumes a long time but 90% of the time was just waiting?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, core-web-vitals, web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint

I am trying to improve my INP. As I am checking the performance panel and notice there is a function takes a very long time to complete, while itself only consumes 0.41ms, and in the timeline chart, the function is doing nothing.

Why it takes so long just to wait? And why this period is not considered "idle"?

Can somebody explain? Thanks!

[image]

update:

May I know which one should I choose?

[image]

Comment: It's probably doing something internally, e.g. compiling or garbage-collecting. You can see it by enabling `Timeline` checkboxes in devtools settings -> Experiments panel.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks a lot. May I know which one should I choose? I have updated the original question with a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: All of them. It's not like they explode.